# the cause of overloading a constructors in java

Tags: constructor, overloading, constructor-overloading

So I just can't seem to understand the problem of overloading. I *know* it is caused by constructors sharing the same parameters; but do that have to be *exactly* the same or will the overload happen if they share one common parameter, or even they if one had three parameters but shares two with another?

Comment: Please check out http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking here.

But Overloading is not only for Constructors. That can be for other methods too.

Here are the rules (My). You can have same method name, but the parameters should be different.

Example: Constructor Overloading

```
public Car()
{
}
private Car(int speed, int maxSpeed)
{
//...
}
public Car(String make, String model)
{
//...
}
```

This is overloading.

But below is illegal with the above constructors.

```
public Car(String color, String make)
{
//...
}
```

Because the JVM wouldn't be able to distinguish the (String make, String model) & (String color, String make) Constructors. Therefore the rule is, parameters should be different (Types and/or the number of parameters).

Again Remember:

```
public void printNames(String name1, String name2)
public void printNames(String x, String y)
```

This is not overloading and even the compiler wouldn't let you do it.

Answer (score 2):

A java class can contain two or more methods with the same name, provided that those methods accept different parameters.  That is called overloading.  When you create overloaded methods every method must have a unique signature.